# How to match 3 lines in txt file and extract string in the middle line

Tags: powershell, match, select-string

Using Powershell I would like to extract a value from text file that is in between two lines that match a pattern.

I'm trying to match 3 lines, 1st & 3rd will always be the same:

```
1st: '  1'
2nd: trying to read... always 2-4 characters
3rd: ' 40'
```

There are multiple occasions where line 1&3 should match this.

I tried with bellow code.

```bsh
$aa=Get-Content $filename1 -Raw
$aaa=$aa  |Where-Object { ( $_ -match '(.\s1)(?:\r\n|[\r\n])*(?:\r\n|[\r\n])(\s40)') }
$aaa
```

I get too much output...maybe it's matching just 1st and 3rd line and many lines in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Regex:

```
$regex = [regex] '\s+1\r?\n(?<secondline>.*)\r?\n\s+40'
$match = $regex.Match($text)
$result = while ($match.Success) {
    $match.Groups['secondline'].Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
} 

$result
```

Where `$text` is the file you read with `$text = Get-Content 'FILENAME' -Raw` like this:

> ```
>   1
> trying to read... always 2-4 characters
>  40
>   1
> another second line
>  40
>   1
> the line you are interested in
>  40
> ```

The result is

```
trying to read... always 2-4 characters
another second line
the line you are interested in
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is usually a poor substitute for a context-sensitive multi-line parser.

Given the document format, I'd simply write one:

```
$grabLine = $false

switch -File($filename1){
  '  1' {
    $grabLine = $true
  }
  ' 40' {
    $grabLine = $false
  }
  default{
    if($grabLine){
      $_
      # break here if you only need one line 
    }
  }
}
```